# should I go for a Ph.D.in electronic/electromagnetism engineering?

Tags: phd, advisor

Hello Academicians and everyone,

As you noticed from my question. I am willing to do a Ph.D. in electronic/electromagnetism engineering. I am very interested in the topic of electromagnetism and its application. I love everything that has to do with Maxwell equations.

Nevertheless, I have a big concern, My Health(burn out, gastritis, stress, migraine). as I am at the beginning of my thirties and had a lot of health issues during my master degree. I had to take many short breaks to get back to the track in the meantime.

I had some professors (who think I am healthy as Batman and don't know what I am facing) who suggested me to do a Ph.D. with them but I am scared to death because of my situation and I don't want to end up in Hospital because I  usually push until I get sick.

I need your advice and suggestion from your sides. How do you manage your stress? how did you manage to successfully finish your Ph.D. without ending in Hospital? or it would be better not going for this Ph.D. in my case?

Thanks

Comment: Voting to close -- we are not medical doctors, and we don't know your situation well enough to advise you do/don't get a PhD. You might consider editing the question (or making a new one) so that it focuses on stress management (strangely, I don't see a general "how to manage stress in grad school" question in our archive), or on accommodations that can/should be made for those with chronic conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no question that stress can kill you. But there are ways to reduce it. One of the big stress factors among students - especially high achieving students - is pushing too hard and never taking a break.

One advantage you have over many others is that you now recognize the issue and can learn to take action before the level becomes unbearable.

One problem with learning is that you are trying to change your brain - physically. To learn requires rewiring the synapses that connect the neurons. But the brain doesn't work as well as it might if you force it to work too hard all the time. You need to give it periods of rest. If you try to force it to learn it will work less efficiently. But that may just induce some people to try harder, increasing the problem and adding stress, but not learning.

To give your brain a break you just need to do something different. It may include physical rest or not. In fact it may include intense physical activity. In grad school I used bicycling as an outlet. 50-100 mile rides. Maybe 35 if time was tight. I rode in a group, fairly fast, but not so fast that we couldn't chat as we rode. As an undergraduate I practiced judo on a college team. I was terrible at it, but it provided a break from studies. Nowadays, I use Tai Chi which is a mind-body fusion exercise. An hour several times a week will make a change in your outlook. Some academic departments actually have groups that regularly do some activity. Tennis. Racketball. Swimming. A computer scientist I know (very high level person) once joined a theatre group.

Moreover, when you are trying to solve a difficult problem, pushing the brain harder may be counterproductive, but giving it a rest lets it work differently. Many researchers have gone to bed with a nasty problem unsolved, only to awake with the solution. It might even come in the middle of a bike ride. Your brain doesn't turn off in these situations, but the overall body structure (including the brain) will work differently.

My advice, then, is to find a way to deal with stress. If you are at a university or similar institution, there may be some "counseling" office that has short courses on such things or people skilled in teaching stress reduction. If you can find ways to manage and reduce stress (you probably can't avoid it altogether) you can function at a higher level whatever you do.

Comment: Thank you so much Buffy . It is really what happening to me, I take a break only once I am sick. You are absolutely right about what you said. Actually, I used to practice Karate ( with black built) but all my problems started after I got spine disc from pushing too much as well in karate. During my the time I was practicing karate, my academic performance and problem solving are quite higher than Now l, even though with less time and effort. I LL have to rework on my lifestyle which goes against me as you said!

Answer (score 1):

The answer probably depends on what you want the degree for. Although grad school can be fun and rewarding, the point of a PhD is ultimately to learn how to conduct original research in your field and (just as importantly) to find a future job doing that original research. Unfortunately, it's extremely difficult to have a research-oriented career outside of academia (although this varies with the field in question), and getting an academic career involves--- regardless of your talent and skill and determination--- being extraordinarily lucky; it's not something you can get just by working hard enough or wanting it enough. Fortunately, if you're mainly interested in working with and studying electromagnetism, there are avenues for doing so outside of getting a PhD that won't tax your health.

Comment: Actually, I loved electromagnitism since I started studying it. This topic I am interested in is concerning the medical care device where electromagnitism is used for scanning and so on. Furthermore,as you said, I want a career in industry where I can see the applications and contribute. So you think it would be better to find a PhD in company where I can combine research and industry?